# Do we need display:block, for a already HTML block element?

Tags: html, css

I recently learned, that html elements are groupped as **Block** and **Inline** Elements.
So if **p** is a **block** element by default, does it mean this is all crossbrowser standart?

While Coding a Website, Do I Need to specify **display:block;** for a **p** tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untill you changed it anyhow ,  p remains block element. you dont need to specify.

Comment: What if p is inside an inline element? Is it still block based, or as a child inline?

Comment: It will be block level , Untill you change it . p remains block but yes its inside inline level element
Like There is inline level element inside block level element <p><span style="color:blue;">blue</span></p>.

Answer (score 1):

No you don't have to,Because p is a block element .

> You can't put block elements inside inline elements. Formatting. By
>   default, inline elements do not force a new line to begin in the
>   document flow. Block elements, on the other hand, typically cause a
>   line break to occur (although, as usual, this can be changed using
>   CSS)

Check this for more information of which all tags are block and inline elements:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp

Comment: unfortunately i cant select 2 accepted answers :( and i cant still reputate... but thank you for the help

Comment: It would, of course, be better if w3schools' lists of which elements were by default block and inline were correct, but they are not.